# How can I free Canvas memory?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have an Object which contains a JavaFX Canvas, and I display images on it. With very large images, sized 4000 x 4000 for example, the canvas consumes a lot of memory.

I want to clear the content to re-use it later.  How can I do that?

Trying the following doesn't help:

`canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(0, 0, getImage().getWidth(), getImage().getHeight());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been recent discussion on the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-August/009598.html) regarding adding a method to [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) to free resources - such a feature, if implemented, would not be available until a future JavaFX release.

As a result of the previously referenced thread, the following platform tweak request has been created: [RT-32242 Canvas should clear its buffered commands on certain clearRect, fillRect calls](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32242) (currently scheduled for implementation for the Java 8 release).

Until that is implemented, you may need to create a new Canvas node and replace the old one with the new one.

Although it's not as functional as a Canvas, perhaps using a [WritableImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) might be sufficient for your operations and may not suffer the same memory issues you are currently encountering with Canvas.  This is because internally a WritableImage is just a buffer of pixel data with no historical record, whereas a Canvas internally keeps a historical record of drawing commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you no longer have a reference to the image Object, you may have to wait until garbage collection is run.  Calls to `clearRect()` only fill the existing image with the background color.